# Do properties default to nil?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, instance-variables, declared-property

If i don't use an ivar for properties, but do this:

```
@interface someClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * someArray;

@end

@implementation someClass

@synthesize someArray = _someArray;

- (void) someMethod
{
    if( self.someArray == nil ){
        // True on the first call?
    }
}


@end
```

The first time I check `self.someArray` it returns `nil`, as does `_someArray`, but is this guaranteed? I read only that ivars are guaranteed to be `nil`, and since I don't declare a ivar (`_someArray` is not an ivar), I am not sure if it will be `nil` everywhere and every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always nil. Objective-C initialises all the variables in a class to nil when it is allocated. Synthesised ivars follow the same rules.

Answer (score 3):

Properties are backed by instance variables if they are synthesized automatically -- so yes, by default such properties will return `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all properties, ivars and static variables have always been defined to be initialized to `nil`. Now with ARC this carries over to `__strong` stack variables (`__strong` being the default for all object pointers).